Explorer - Dev on x86 but release for arm
I just added the lib Explorer but my dev env is on x86 while the prod env is an arm.
Is there a simple way to make the release for arm ? as other languages do with just setting an env var

The Elixir compiler produces bytecode which is, I believe, independant of the architecture. It will then be executed by the Erlang virtual machine, so it should work on ARM. Try it.

Yep, but Explorer makes use of NIF which depends on the arch

I've just ended up building the release in prod on deploy
